# Magento 1.9.X: How to assign data to quote?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, quote

I need to assign data to quote, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample code to add data in quote and you can modify according to your requirement

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('product_id');

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($product)->setQty('product_qty');
    $quote->addItem($quoteItem);

    $quote->setStore($store);
    $billingAddressData = array(
    'firstname' => 'Test',
    'lastname' => 'Test',
    'street' => 'Wall Street 10',
    'city' => 'Somewhere',
    'postcode' => '123456',
    'telephone' => '123456',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
    ); // billing address
    $shippingAddressData = array(
    'firstname' => 'Test',
    'lastname' => 'Test',
    'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
    'city' => 'Somewhere',
    'postcode' => '123456',
    'telephone' => '123456',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
    );// shipping address
    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($billingAddressData);
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddressData);
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
    ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
    ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```